# mount: /new_root: wrong fs type, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: linux, boot, partition, manjaro

I am farely new to Linux in general, but I can use the command line to do some basic stuff.
Currently I am using Manjaro KDE.
Yesterday I followed allong with the Book Linux from Scratch to learn more about Linux.
The last thing I did was that I made my main partition smaller by 25 gb and created a new one (using cfdisk).
Everything was fine, expect when I logged into Manjaro today, I got the errors:

```
mount: /new_root: wrong fs type, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

and

```
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
```

and was thrown into an emergency shell. As I said, i can use the command line to create,
copy and edit files, but this looks way too advanced for me.

EDIT

The last thing I did before everything broke was:

1st I shrinked my main partition by 25.6 gb using cfdisk.

2nd I created a new partition (20 gb) using cfdisk.

3rd I mounted the new partition.

4th I created a new ext4 filesystem on the new partition.

Then I shut down my pc and when I startet it today, it brought me straight into an emergency shell

I have already tried:

```
mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 / (in the recovery shell, same Error).
mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/nvme (from a live usb stick, same Error).
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error ocured and how I can rescue my data?

Comment: Without detailed description with commands you've been running, it is difficult to guess what happened and whether there is a possibility to fix it. Please feel free to add as much details as possible.

Comment: I am very sorry, but this is my first question. The last thing I did before everything broke was: 1. I shrinked my main partition by 20.6 gb using cfdisk. 2. I created a new partition (20 gb) using cfdisk. 3. I mounted the new partition. 4. I created a new ext4 filesystem on the new partition. Then I shut down my pc and when I startet it today, it brought me straight into an emergency shell. First I tried running mount /dev/nvme0n1p4  / from within the emergency shell, and then I tried mount /dev/nvme0n1p  / from a manjaro live usb stick. That's everything I remember.

Comment: How did you manage to mount new partition (step 3) when there was no filesystem at all?

Comment: Sorry, I propably messed up the steps a bit. 3 and 4 were propably switched. I did this when I could still use my pc like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not use `resize2fs` to shrink the filesystem before using `cfdisk` to shrink the partition it's located in, you have caused the tail end of the filesystem to be cut off. The system is now detecting that the filesystem claims to be larger than the partition it's located in, which is an error.

While an ext2/3/4 filesystem can be *enlarged* while it's being used, *shrinking* still requires unmounting it first. And it looks like `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is your root filesystem, which cannot be easily unmounted from `/` and requires special steps for mounting to `/` (mount it to somewhere else, minimize the number of processes running, and use `pivot_root` to switch to the new root filesystem), so the chances are high you did not use the proper procedure for resizing your **root** filesystem.

The easiest way to resize a root filesystem would have been to boot from external live media, and using that to resize the root filesystem of your installed OS while it's completely unmounted. The other alternative would be to ensure the filesystem resizing tool is present in `initramfs`, and then use the boot options to interrupt the boot within the initramfs boot phase, while the root filesystem is not yet mounted, and do the filesystem shrinking within the resulting emergency shell.

The problem now is that resizing the filesystem requires it to be free of errors first. Having a part of the filesystem violently cut off is definitely an error.

You would need to boot the system from live media, then use it to mount & backup the contents of the new partition you created (if there is any), then delete that partition and restore the `/dev/nvme0n1p4` partition back to its original size. Then you should be able to run `e2fsck -C0 /dev/nvme0n1p4` on it to check for errors (and hopefully fix any that might have been caused by the partial overwriting of the tail end of the filesystem).

Then, still in the live media environment, mount the root filesystem to a temporary location with

```
mkdir /media/nvme
mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/nvme
```

and use it to edit the `/etc/fstab` of the installed OS (now at `/media/nvme/etc/fstab`) to temporarily comment out any reference to the new partition you created.

Then you can exit the live media and verify your installed OS again boots normally.

Then boot with the live media again to resize the root filesystem properly:

1.) First use `resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p4 <new-size>` to resize the filesystem inside the partition. If you know the exact number of sectors the partition will have after resizing, you can use that as the `<new-size>` value. Otherwise, you should shrink the filesystem to slightly *smaller* size than you intend to shrink the partition to, to guard against rounding (and base-2 vs. base-10) errors in unit conversions.

2.) Then shrink the partition containing the filesystem. You can also create the new partition using the free space as part of this step.

3.) Exit the live media and boot into the installed OS to confirm it still works normally. If you resized the filesystem to a size smaller than the new partition size, you can now use `resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p4` to auto-detect the current partition size and expand the filesystem to exactly match it. (Yes, you can do this while the filesystem is mounted.)

4.) Now you can proceed with creating the filesystem on your new partition, uncommenting/adding the `/etc/fstab` line for it, and mounting the new filesystem.